# Local degrees for $n=1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

In Hatcher, p. 136, prop. 2.30, the author needs the fact that $id_{S^n}$ induces an isomorphism $H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n,S^n \setminus \{x\})$. For $n>1$ this map sits in the following part of the exact sequence in homology: $$0 = H_n(S^n \setminus \{x\}) \to H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n, S^n \setminus \{x\}) \to H_{n-1}(S^n \setminus \{x\})=0$$ which is the result. At $n=1$ however we are left with $$0 = H_1(S^1 \setminus \{x\}) \to H_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1, S^1 \setminus \{x\}) \xrightarrow{\varphi} H_0(S^1 \setminus \{x\})=\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 \to 0$$ and since surjective maps $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ are injective this gives $\varphi =0$ and the result follows, but Hatcher doesn't mention this last little argument, which makes me wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: As far as I can see, all Hatcher says about this is that the isomorphism comes from the exact sequence for the pair. So it looks like he's expecting you to be able to work these details out for yourself.

Comment: I'm asking because that's the first time I see him leaving anything to the reader. But I suppose you're right.

Comment: As you were able to work the details out for yourself at exactly the right point, it is clearly the right book for you! $\ddot{\smile}$.